# Multiple inline SVG in HTML not displayed correctly

Tags: html, svg

I have several SVG converted from PDF (converted using **pdftocairo**), and can be viewed in a browser without any problems.

One of the SVG is [here](https://gist.github.com/K-JW/cfe00eb244ded28b32e0a6f67d88a6de?short_path=d88c040#file-aplanarity-svg).

When I embed this SVG into HTML, it displays correctly, but when I embed several different SVG into the same HTML, the display will not be correct.

Details as follows:
[image]

**So why multiple inline SVG in HTML not displayed correctly?** I observed that only the first inline SVG can be displayed correctly.

Moreover, the HTML with embedded SVG at [here](https://gist.github.com/K-JW/69dc8c78498323bac9380ce3cdb4ccca#file-example-html).

Comment: without looking at your code; most likely duplicate ``id`` values

Comment: Yep, the SVG inside `#plot_HadrTotalChMult` uses the same ID's as the SVG inside `#plot_Aplanarity`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly a clash of `id` attributes.  The `id` attributes need to be unique on the page.  But I expect your two SVGs reuse `id` values for two different things.  For example each might have a `id="glyph0-1"` where each one refers to a different font glyph.

You'll need to either embed the SVGs a different way - such as via an `<img>`, `<embed>`, `<iframe>` etc.  Or rename any duplicate `id`s in the second, or any subsequent, SVGs.  If you're lucky, perhaps pdftocairo has an option for this.

Comment: Or load the SVG in a DOM element with **shadowDOM** See: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd